# after_initialize & after_find callbacks order in Active Record object life cycle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

From the Rails Guides. Callbacks could hook into Active Record Object's life cycle. In the order of execution, they're (copied from Rails Guides):

#### Creating an Object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_create`
- `around_create`
- `after_create`
- `after_save`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

#### Updating an Object

- `before_validation`
- `after_validation`
- `before_save`
- `around_save`
- `before_update`
- `around_update`
- `after_update`
- `after_save`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

#### Destroying an Object

- `before_destroy`
- `around_destroy`
- `after_destroy`
- `after_commit/after_rollback`

I am wondering where to put the `after_initialize` and `after_find` into above? I think `after_initialize` should put before `before_validation` and `after_find` does not belongs to any three of them. Am I correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `after_initialize` and `after_find` callbacks are the two special callbacks.

The only way to define callbacks for the `after_find` and `after_initialize` events is to define them as `methods`. If you try declaring them as `handlers`,they’ll be silently ignored.

From the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

> `after_find` and `after_initialize` callback is triggered for each
>   object that is found and instantiated by a finder, with
>   `after_initialize` being triggered after new objects are instantiated
>   as well.

From the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find)

> The `after_initialize` callback will be called whenever an Active
>   Record object is instantiated, either by directly using new or when a
>   record is loaded from the database. It can be useful to avoid the need
>   to directly override your Active Record initialize method.
>
> The `after_find` callback will be called whenever Active Record loads
>   a record from the database. `after_find` is called before
>   `after_initialize` if both are defined.
>
> The `after_initialize` and `after_find` callbacks have no **before_*
>   counterparts**, but they can be registered just like the other Active
>   Record callbacks.
>
> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   after_initialize do |user|
>     puts "You have initialized an object!"
>   end
>
>   after_find do |user|
>     puts "You have found an object!"
>   end
> end
>
> >> User.new
> You have initialized an object!
> => #<User id: nil>
>
> >> User.first
> You have found an object!
> You have initialized an object!
> => #<User id: 1>
> ```

***where to put the `after_initialize` and `after_find` in the AR object life cycle?***

Since they are different from all other callbacks and also they don't have **before_* counterparts**,so the author(referring to [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find) author here) might be interested in putting them separately as they are special case.

And finally I would agree with in putting `after_initialize` before `before_validation`. It might be the case.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I have googled for hours and tried everything. I read a tip in older manuals that after_find only triggers if `explicit implementation is defined ("def after_find")`, thought that it was still so, missed the syntax you have in your answer in the new guide.  I don't find that it has to be done that way in the new guides though. Thank you again.