# Rails Model Callback Not Saving Instance Method Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, callback

I'm struggling to make my model callback functions behave properly :(
Using Rails 5.2.4.1, Ruby 2.6.3 and pg ~> 0.21

I have a model "Batch" that I want to have automatically calculate and update its own "Value" attribute once its "Price" and "Quantity" values are greater than zero.

```
  def change
    create_table :batches do |t|
      t.references :product, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :currency, foreign_key: true
      t.string :batch_number, null: false
      t.string :status, null: false, default: "pending"
      t.integer :quantity, null: false, default: 0
      t.integer :price, null: false, default: 0
      t.integer :value, null: false, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my seed file I create some Batch instances with specified Quantity and then Price, and leave the value to default to 0 (this is to be added later when creating an Order instance):

```
batch1 = Batch.new(
  product_id: Product.last.id,
  batch_number: "0001-0001-0001",
  quantity: 1800
)

if batch1.valid?
  batch1.save
  p batch1
else
  p first_batch1.errors.messages
end

batch1.price = 3
batch1.save
```

Then my troubles begin...
I've tried a few approaches similar to the below:

```
after_find :calculate_value

def calculate_value
  self.value = price * quantity if value != price * quantity
end
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something very obvious here, but **the value never seems to update**.

I've tried adding save into the method but it doesn't seem to work either. I'm finding some of the other behaviours with saving in these callbacks very strange.

For example, I assign a Currency to a Batch through a join table with this instance method:

```
  after_find :assign_currency

  def assign_currency
    self.currency_id = currency.id unless currency.nil?
    # save
  end
```

If I uncomment that "save" (or make it "self.save") then the seed file creates the Batches but then fails to create the join table, returning {:batch=>["must exist"]}. Yet in the console, the batch does:

```
[#<Batch:0x00007fb874ad0aa0
  id: 1,
  product_id: 1,
  batch_number: "0001-0001-0001",
  status: "pending",
  quantity: 1800,
  currency_id: nil,
  price: 0,
  value: 0,
  created_at: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 00:38:42 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 09 Jan 2020 00:38:42 UTC +00:00>,
```

I'm still new to rails so would be very grateful for any advice or suggestions whatsoever! This feels like it should be simple and it's driving me crazy...

Comment: I think you should use before_save instead of after_find

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `before_validation` callback instead of an `after_find`. The reason I'd recommend that is because in an `after_find`, the `value` column will be populated only when the object is loaded using finder (`.find`, `.find_or_create`), and hence, the you would not be able to validate the `value` column before saving. In fact, during initial save, the `value` column will be empty.

The order of execution of callbacks is as follows:

```
before_validation
after_validation
before_save
around_save
before_create
around_create
after_create
after_save
after_commit/after_rollback
```

So, in your case, this could work:

```
before_validation :calculate_value, if: :price_or_quantity_changed?

validates :value, presence: true  # This can be added because the before_validation callback will ensure that value is present

def calculate_value
  self.value = price * quantity if value != price * quantity
end

private

def price_or_quantity_changed?
  self.price_changed? || self.quantity_changed?
end
```

`_changed?` methods are from the [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) module which helps us keep track of values that have changed in a record.

However, if you would want to use `after_find`, I think [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125577/5362761) may help you understand it more.

You could use `after_find` after defining it as a method as follows:

```
def after_find
  <your code to set value>
end
```

[after_initialize & after_find callbacks order in Active Record object life cycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124018/after-initialize-after-find-callbacks-order-in-active-record-object-life-cycle)

Answer (score -1):

how about this in your model?

```
after_find :calculate_value

def calculate_value
  self.value = self.price * self.quantity if self.value != self.price * self.quantity
end
```